# How to authenticate a MongoDB connection similar to .pgpass file mechanism?

Tags: php, security, mongodb, authentication, encryption

I want to authenticate my MongoDB connections from the php driver but I do not want my passwords stored in clear text in my codebases.  I would prefer a mechanism similar to Postgresql's .pgpass file.

I would like to authenticate using a file on the system somewhere so that my MongoDB password is not distributed to dozens of computers around the country via our version control repositories and service providers.

If MongoDB and/or the php driver do not have this functionality out of the box, the best alternative I can think of is to have a heavily encrypted password in the codebase with a private key file on the machines to decrypt the password on the fly for MongoDB authentication.  Using a combination of persistent connections and/or APC caching I can reduce the performance hit of having to decrypt a file for every connection.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how .pgpass in Postres works, and I can't really imagine how that works with PHP - or how you would be distributing that file in your VCS differently..
It sounds to me just like a random file in the filesystem you can simply run

```
$password = file_get_contents("/home/username/.mongodbpass");
```

MongoDB 2.4 supports external authentication mechanisms such as Kerberos and LDAP authentication if that is something you are looking for.
Alternatively, MongoDB 2.6 supports X509 authentication, but won't be released until early next year.

Other then that there is only standard username/password combo.